# Reading specific section of App.config

Tags: c#, .net, oracle

I'm trying to get the values from the `oracle.manageddataaccess.client` section in my `App.config` file. This section looks like this:

```
<oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
    <version number="*">
        <dataSources>
            <dataSource alias="alias1" descriptor="connection string 1" />
            <dataSource alias="alias2" descriptor="connection string 2" />
        </dataSources>
    </version>
</oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
```

I've tried using the `ConfigurationManager` API to read the values, but I haven't had any luck.

With:

`Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);`

`config.AppSettings.Settings["oracle.manageddataaccess.client"]`

just returns an empty string.

`config.Sections` seems to only work for tags that are explicitly a `section` tag.

I just need to be able to read the `dataSource` values in this section.

Update:
`config.Sections["oracle.manageddataaccess.client"].SectionInformation` returns information about the section, and the `GetRawXml()` is getting closer to what I want, but I'm trying to get a specific subset of this.

Comment: So you mean you just put this in app.config without declaring section?

Comment: There is a `section` defined for `oracle.manageddataaccess.client`, it's created automatically with the Oracle EF provider. But calling `config.Sections["oracle.manageddataaccess.client"]` returns the `section` tag info, which isn't what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find exactly what I was looking for, but I found a way around it.
If anyone else has the same issue, you can use XDocument and Linq to filter for what you need. You need to include your `using` statements: `System.Linq` and `System.Xml.Linq`

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(config.Sections["oracle.manageddataaccess.client"].SectionInformation.GetRawXml());
var value = from node in doc.Descendants("dataSource")
            where node.Attribute("alias").Value == whatever
            select node.Attribute("descriptor").Value;
```